# full-screen games keep minimising right after launching them

Tags: windows-10, gaming

I've been having this issue a very long time now, but it just got annoying enough to try and fix it.

Every time I launch a full-screen game, doesn't matter which game, it runs fine for a while but then within a minute it minimises. Most games handle this fine but BF4 decides that it doesn't want to process my input anymore so I have to restart the game. Every full-screen game does this every time I launch it.

At first I thought it was some video card issue, but I recently switched from AMD to Nvidia and it's still happening. I also tried connecting another mouse and keyboard and even used another network port on my motherboard.

I've also tried the following potential solutions without success:

- Disable f.lux
- Disable malwarebytes
- Enable quiet hours for notifications

I'm running Windows 10 Pro (with the anniversary update) with a GTX 1080 and some 3rd gen i7

Comment: When this behavior is experienced, check your task manager for a process called `wermgr.exe`. Does it appear to start and stop frequently?

Comment: @jatuttle0 I can't see `wermgr.exe` in task manager at all.

Comment: Does the problem persist if the game is rendered in `windowed-fullscreen` mode?

Comment: That's weird. :)  Does it still happen if you log in as a new/different user?

Comment: @jatuttle0 it also happens in windowed-fullscreen (borderless) mode :(

Comment: Haven't tried that yet, @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 - I'll try it tomorrow when I get home!

Comment: Do you have any USB devices disconnecting when this happens? I have a computer that does this and every time it happens the USB disconnect sound goes off. I haven't diagnosed which devices is doing it yet, but something probably has a loose connection.

Comment: @LAROmega Not that I know of. I don't hear the disconnect sound.

Comment: Now the game minimises when I launch it, then I see it in a windowed mode, when I click it it jumps back to full screen and works again. Still don't know why it keeps minimising though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is a useful answer for anyone else, but for me the issues stopped after the August 2016 Windows 10 Anniversary update.